# PHP / Javascript - how to locate suitable place for code?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I'd like to modify WP plugin's code.
This plugin dynamically creates table, assigns color to cells of this table.

I'd like to put a JavaScript code in this plugin, so the color of cells with a certain text inside is changed.

I have the code, it should work as it has been tested before.
I just don't know where to put this code to make it work. I tried to put it in the PHP file which creates the table but code in this file is not ended with "?>" which I suppose means that somewhere else is the rest of the code which is being added in the proces of creating the table.

It's possible that the table is being loaded via AJAX.
I have access to all the files so I can provide if necessary.

Would anyone be so kind and helped me locate suitable place for my code?

Comment: *code in this file is not ended with "?>"* - That's okay. The closing `?>` is optional, and is often omitted to prevent accidental output of whitespace. It doesn't mean the file is 'continued' somewhere else.

Comment: I tried adding `echo "
<script>
function f_color() {
----code here }
f_color()
</script>`
But it didn't do the trick. I have a parsing error.

Answer (score 0):

To add more javascript functionality to the third party plugin you should add your additional javascript code with wordpress' own function [wp_enqueue_script](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script). Somewhere in the third party plugin code the plugin is initialized. There you can add your file with the additional javascript code.

Comment: So that would mean that my script would be loaded each time any page of my project is loaded and used only if certain class is found (the script code refers to class names), right?
I could place it with the $in_footer parameter as true so that way it would be loaded after the table is created?